# Beginner - I want the scroll bar to move down with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Following guys, I used the code:

```
window.scrollBy (0, window.innerHeight)
```

And yes, it scrolls down the instagram home page.

However, when I go to my story, and see who viewed it, I want him to scroll the story's NOT scroll bar on the home page.

When I open the console and use the code I mentioned above, it returns me undefined and does not do what I want.

How do I scroll the bar of people who have viewed my story? Not from the home page (complete)?

EDIT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LALX3.png)

Comment: I tested with 

var storyBlock = document.querySelector('.pbNvD.fPMEg') storyBlock.scrollBy(0, storyBlock.innerHeight)

 But it didn't work :/ – Matheus Nascimento

Comment: @Sergio maybe my difficulty is in selecting ... Tried to select practically all divs, and really selected, however, none worked when I try to scroll the page :/

Can you test with people who view your story on instagram?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#scroll-child')
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var childBlock = document.querySelector('.child')
  childBlock.scroll(0, 50)
})
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: crimson;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child-content {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button id="scroll-child">
    scroll child content!
  </button>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-content">
      something1
      something2
      something3
      something4
      something5
      something6
      something7
      something8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. find your story block with its css selector:

```js
var storyBlock = document.querySelector('#my-story-block-id')
```

2. scroll inside block

```js
storyBlock.scroll(0, storyBlock.innerHeight)
```

Comment: I tested with

var storyBlock = document.querySelector('.pbNvD.fPMEg')
storyBlock.scrollBy(0, storyBlock.innerHeight)

But it didn't work :/

Comment: maybe my difficulty is in selecting ... Tried to select practically all divs, and really selected, however, none worked when I try to scroll the page :/

Can you test with people who view your story on instagram?